# Unresolved external symbol error using uint16_t c++

Tags: c++, lnk2019

*endianness.cpp*

```
#include "endianness.h"

#include <cstdint>

 using namespace io;

 void switch_endianness(uint16_t* n)
 {
     *n = (*n >> 8) | (*n << 8);
 }

 void switch_endianness(uint32_t* n)
 {
     ...
 }

 void switch_endianness(uint64_t* n)
 {
     ...
 }
```

*endianness.h*

```
#ifndef ENDIANNESS_H
#define ENDIANNESS_H

#include <cstdint>


namespace io
{
    void switch_endianness(uint16_t* n);

    void switch_endianness(uint32_t* n);

    void switch_endianness(uint64_t* n);
}

#endif
```

Trying to test out my `switch_endianness` function in *app.cpp*, I get an unresolved symbol error:

```
LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl io::switch_endianness(unsigned short *)" (?switch_endianness@io@@YAXPEAG@Z) referenced in function main
```

*app.cpp*

```
#ifndef TEST_BUILD

#include <iostream>
#include "io/endianness.h"

int main(int argn, char** argv)
{
    std::uint16_t y = 0x0000;
    io::switch_endianness(&y);
    std::cout << y;
}

#endif
```

How I understand and read thus far, its a linking/reference problem. I think my code is fine and should compile and run as intended, I did 'include in project' to my `endianness` files, perhaps there is something trivial I'm missing or doing wrong with referencing? I really can't seem to solve this.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `std::uint16_t`.

Comment: check compiler docs, it may have intrinsic functions  for this , e.g. like shown here https://mklimenko.github.io/english/2018/08/22/robust-endian-swap/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my *endianness.cpp* file I changed the function declarations to include the folder directory it was in and now it works.. (As it was complaining about this in the header file not being able to find function definition)

```
 void io::switch_endianness(uint16_t* n)
 {
     ...
 }
```

Comment: Or enclose the function definitions inside a `namespace io { ... }` like they were declared, otherwise they are defined at global scope.

Comment: @dxiv oh yes thank you! sorry im a newbie to c++